Upgrading Firebase-tools is breaking my react app URL's that contain params
I have a react app which I've been working on for years and is hosted in firebase. Everything has been working smoothly for years. My version of firebase-tools was 11.17.0
In my react app, I have all requests route to the host, where it does some logic to determine where the request is coming from, and then routes accordingly.
My function was targeting node 16.
I recently upgraded firebase-tools to latest version 13.7.3, so I could upgrade the target node engine.
After I deploy using this latest version (and changing nothing else), Any URL that has params in the URL starts receiving error.
So, if my base url is https://www.myapp.com, this loads.
But when I try to access https://www.myapp.com?x=23 or https://www.myapp.com/23/23
The page immediately throws an error I see in console as :
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
Since no other code has changed, and only the CLi is upgraded, how do I debug this? What could be breaking here?

could be an HTTP call (httpsCallable, fetch, or otherwise) is returning HTML or other garbage back instead of expected data. Check to see if there's anything suspicious in the your browser's Dev Tools > Network tab?

After further investigating, the upgrade of the tools messed up my firebase.json file, removing the function:{} node. no idea why, but that was the issue. I updated the freibase-functions , added that functions node back into firebase.json and it's working
